# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING blocking ip

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, syntax-error

Here is line 37;

```
$write = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `trial' VALUES (" '', '".$ip."', '1' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

The error may be coming from further up.. But I'm not quite sure :S

I am trying to block the ip of a

Answer (score 3):

There are *both* PHP and SQL syntax errors in the same line of code.

You incorrectly quoted your table name, have misplaced double quotes in your `VALUES` expression and have misplaced parentheses in your `or die` statement. Here's the fixed statement:

```
$write = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `trial` VALUES ( '', '".mysql_real_escape_string($ip)."', '1' )") or die(mysql_error());
```

(Additionally, yes, I did throw in that `mysql_real_escape_string()` in case you didn't escape your query variables.)

Comment: +1, for the complete answer, addressing all his bugs.

Comment: @codaddict: It took me longer than the 5-minute edit window to get them all in though :/

Answer (score 0):

You have some " inside the VALUES() that are not escaped. And trial is quoted wrong. (as codaddict mentioned)

```
$write = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `trial` VALUES ('', '".$ip."', '1') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong quote here:

```
`trial'
      ^
```